# Configuring memcached with django

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, memcached

I'm working with an ubuntu 16.04 VPS, where I have a django 1.8 app running using uwsgi and nginx. I want to install memcached for django , so I've been looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/. I want to use pylibmc  as my memcached client.

Based on this, I've added:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '/tmp/memcached.sock',
    }
}
```

to my settings.py. But when I run

```
(myenv) deploy@server:~$ sudo systemctl status memcached
● memcached.service - memcached daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset
Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-02-17 11:21:07 EST; 5s ago
Main PID: 5562 (memcached)
CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
        └─5562 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
```

Based on the output it appears that memcached is using an ip address and port (if I understand correctly) .How can I configure memcached to use the django socket backend?

Answer (score 2):

Modify `/etc/memcached.conf`

Comment `-p` and `-l` - This disables TCP sockets

Add `-s /tmp/memcached.sock` and restart the daemon

https://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached